# Octave how to compare matrix elements efficiently

Tags: compare, octave

I have a large matrix and I would like to compare the adjacent elements to verify that the values are close to being equal.

For example, in this sequence 1006, 1004,999, 1000, 1003, 6, 1005, 1003 ..... the value 6 is not "close to" 1003 or 1005.
I would like an efficient method for doing the comparison.

Here is slow code to find anything outside of the range. It takes 190 seconds on my old computer.

Thank you.

```
big = 1e5;
tic;
a = 0;
x = rand(100,big);
for ii = 1:100
  for jj = 1:big-1;
    y = x(ii,jj) / x(ii,jj+1);
    if (or(y < 0.999,y > 1.001))   a++;
    endif  
  endfor;
endfor;
toc
```

Answer (score 3):

Use vectorization instead of loop:

```
y = x(:, 1:end-1) ./ x(:, 2:end);
a = nnz(y < 0.999 | y > 1.001);
```

Comment: For extra brownie points, I suspect that in theory using a transposed version of this problem could optimise things even further, due to the column-major-order nature of matlab/octave, but I'm not sure how much difference that would make in practice :)

Comment: Nope. Actually takes longer. Huh.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou Column extraction should be faster than row extraction. However `a = sum(y(:) < 0.999 | y(:) > 1.001);` is slightly fatser than `nnz`.

Comment: Or this `t=y(:) < 0.999;t|=y(:) > 1.001;a=sum(t);`

Comment: "Column extraction should be faster than row extraction" yes that's why I naively assumed that putting the 10e5-sized dimension in the columns would make it faster, but I was wrong. So probably the order of operations in this particular example isn't what I assumed it was!